# Why can't flyback work when the duty cycle is greater than 0.5?

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, flyback

I read [this document](https://techweb.rohm.com/knowledge/acdc/acdc_pwm/acdc_pwm01/940) talking about [flyback design](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flyback_converter), and I am curious about why, when the duty cycle is greater than 0.5, do we need to adjust the VOR to make sure the duty cycle is less than 0.5?

What's happened when flyback worked in a duty cycle greater than 0.5?

[image]

Answer (score 10):

Unlike the forward converter, there is no *theoretical* limit for the duty ratio of the flyback converter. This is discussed in this [thread](https://e2e.ti.com/support/power-management-group/power-management/f/power-management-forum/546358/maximum-duty-cycle-of-a-flyback-converter) and intuitively, you understand that too large a duty ratio induces a very narrow conduction time for the diode which is not ideal. To understand the maths behind the justification, it is interesting to resort to a graph showing the voltage across the primary-side inductance during the two switching events of a continuous-conduction-mode-operated (CCM) flyback converter:

[image]

This is an excerpt from my last [book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1949267512) on transfer functions of switching converters. To determine the dc transfer characteristic of the flyback converter, you can apply the volt-second balance law which states that the average voltage across an inductor at *steady-state* is 0 V. To apply this law, simply graphically represent the instantaneous voltage across the primary during the on- and off-times. At equilibrium, the areas or the V-s applied during \$DT_{sw}\$ and \$(1-D)T_{sw}\$ are equal. From that simple equation, you obtain the dc transfer characteristic of the CCM flyback converter.

So you see that if you change the turns ratio \$N\$ for a given operating point, the reflected voltage will scale up or down while the duty ratio will be adjusted to maintain \$V_{out}\$ in regulation. In other words, look at the below calculations for different turns ratios where the duty ratio changes:

[image]

That is the reason why designers often start by determining the turns ratio based on the selected MOSFET and its \$BV_{DSS}\$. The goal is to reduce the rms burden on the transistor by reflecting as much voltage as you can. From this value, the duty ratio is determined:

[image]

As usual, this is a matter of tradeoff between various parameters such as stress, rms currents, available components etc. Finally, you will see in controllers specs for flyback that the maximum duty ratio is often in the range of 80-90%. The best is to create a sheet with a solver and play on the different turns ratio options to see hows the other parameters are affected. It is an iterative process for sure.

Comment: Hi @Verbal Kint, 

I think it is more clear now, but why does this document suggest us to reduce the duty to <0.5?
based on your answer, it will affect the component stress, so when we design the flyback we usually focus on the primary side MOSFET. that is the reason why duty needs to be < 0.5.

Comment: @PowerJJ, I am not sure why they implied 50% for the duty ratio design. I have seen high-volume 65-W ac-dc converters operated on universal mains working with a duty ratio well beyond 50% in the valley of the bulk - looks like the final quote from Roy Batty : ) and it is difficult to make it lower at the lowest input considering a ratio of 1 to almost 4 in the rectified voltage input (universal mains input). Read this excellent [paper](http://www.deltartp.com/dpel/dpelconferencepapers/HFPC95%20notebook%20ac-dc%20adapter-charger.pdf) from the Delta folks and learn about DCM/CCM boundary.

Comment: Hi @Verbal Kint,

When you design the flyback, may I know how did you decide on the turn ratio or duty?

Comment: Hello @PowerJJ, I start with the MOSFET selection, usually a 600- or 650-V type for universal mains applications. Look at the paper I referenced, this is the method I use.

Comment: Hi @Vrtbal Kint,

I see, thnaks.

Comment: Hi @Verbal Kint,

How did you draw the Mathcad about the RMS current?

Answer (score 4):

The simplest explanation may just be the volt-second balance.

If you apply a pulse of Vin for time Ton to charge the magnetic field with input current, it takes the same amount of volt-seconds to reset the magnetic field, and the primary has the reflected VOR over it for time Toff.

So, to run in discontinuous current mode, whatever energy you charge into coil must have time to come out of the coil before a new charging cycle starts.

Otherwise the applied energy would just keep accumulating in coil if it has no time to come out from it.

So at 50% duty, Ton and Toff are equal, and so will Vin and VOR. Of course VOR could be allowed to be higher than VIN to allow higher duty cycle, but it will just make the component selection more expensive and difficult. Increasing duty means increasing VOR and components need to be designed to withstand it, and it will affect transformer ratio and inductance, ripple current ratio etc.

So even if it might be possible, it is not practical.

Comment: What is the quantity with unit volt-second?

Comment: Can the secondary pull energy out of the magnetic field faster than the primary puts it in?  If so, that would allow a duty cycle > 50%.